# Using Jquery to Dynamically Add Text Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I'm trying to add text fields that correspond to a user's selection in a select input. Ideally if a user selects the option with value "created_at" a text input field should be created inside the div "search_input_div" which is, at first, just an empty div.

***************Edit - Something I forgot to mention ************

The "search_column_select" select is created by another button. So it doesn't exist when the page is loaded, I'm not sure if how/if this affects the functionality.

***************End of Edit*******

For some reason nothing happens why I use the following code:

JS

```
 $('#search_column_select').change(function(){
        if($("#search_column_select").val() == 'created_at'){
            $('#search_input_div').html("<input class='search_input' placeholder='(YYYY-MM-DD) or (YYYY-MM)'/>");
        }
    });
```

And just in case it matters here is the HTML:

HTML:

```
<div class="search_box" id="search_column_div">
    <select id='search_column_select'>
<option value='select'>search by...</option>
<option value='created_at'>by date created</option>
<option value='street_address'>by street address</option>
</select>
</div>
        <div id="search_input_div">
            <!-- Search_input text field goes here -->
        </div>
```

If anyone can point out where I went wrong or how to fix this I'd greatly appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: It works for me http://jsfiddle.net/DAtA8/

Comment: Answer updated to reflect your update in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you add your javascript code when the document is ready

http://jsfiddle.net/4Jt5q/1/

```
$(function(){ 
    $('#search_column_select').change(function(){
        if($("#search_column_select").val() == 'created_at'){
            $('#search_input_div').html("<input class='search_input' placeholder='(YYYY-MM-DD) or (YYYY-MM)'/>");
        }
    });
});
```

What this does is to wrap the jQuery event addition into a `$(function(){...});` so now, when your document is ready and `search_column_select` exists, your javascript will be triggered.

#### Update

Since it is created dynamically you have to either add the `change` listener after it is created or use event delegation like this:

```
$(document).on('change', '#search_column_select', function(){
    if($("#search_column_select").val() == 'created_at'){
        $('#search_input_div').html("<input class='search_input' placeholder='(YYYY-MM-DD) or (YYYY-MM)'/>");
    }
});
```

Instead of `document` you can also add the direct parent of the `'#search_column_select'`.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the solution and for explaining where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the jQuery into a document-ready function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#search_column_select').change(function(){
        if($("#search_column_select").val() == 'created_at'){
            $('#search_input_div').html("<input class='search_input' placeholder='(YYYY-MM-DD) or (YYYY-MM)'/>");
        }
    });
});
```